# Can't create Druid ingestion task through API

Tags: druid

When I send JSON ingestion specification to Druid overlord API I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 11:44:18 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.4.10.v20180503)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "error": "Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.indexing.common.task.IndexTask] value failed: null"
}
```

If I change `index` task type to `index_parallel`, then I get this:

```
{
    "error": "Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.indexing.common.task.batch.parallel.ParallelIndexSupervisorTask] value failed: null"
}
```

**Using same ingestion spec through Druid's web UI works fine.**

Here is the ingestion spec that I use(slightly modified to hide sensitive data):

```
{
    "type": "index_parallel",
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "daily_xport_test",
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "MONTH",
        "queryGranularity": "NONE",
        "rollup": false
      },
      "parser": {
        "type": "string",
        "parseSpec": {
          "format": "json",
          "timestampSpec": {
            "column": "dateday",
            "format": "auto"
          },
          "dimensionsSpec": {
            "dimensions": [
              {
                "type": "string",
                "name": "id",
                "createBitmapIndex": true
              },
              {
                "type": "long",
                "name": "clicks_count_total"
              },
              {
                "type": "long",
                "name": "ctr"
              },
              "deleted",
              "device_type",
              "target_url"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ioConfig": {
      "type": "index_parallel",
      "firehose": {
        "type": "static-google-blobstore",
        "blobs": [
          {
            "bucket": "data-test",
            "path": "/sample_data/daily_export_18092019/000000000000.json.gz"
          }
        ],
        "filter": "*.json.gz$"
      },
      "appendToExisting": false
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "index_parallel",
      "maxNumSubTasks": 1,
      "maxRowsInMemory": 1000000,
      "pushTimeout": 0,
      "maxRetry": 3,
      "taskStatusCheckPeriodMs": 1000,
      "chatHandlerTimeout": "PT10S",
      "chatHandlerNumRetries": 5
    }
  }
```

Overlord API URI looks like this:

```
http://host:8081/druid/indexer/v1/task
```

HTTPie command to send API request:

```sh
http --print=Hhb  POST http://host:8081/druid/indexer/v1/task < test_spec.json
```

**Also, I get the same issue if I try to send ingestion task using DruidHook class in Airflow**

Comment: Have you tried looking in the druid log on the overlord to see any more details about the error?

Comment: @Michael I've tried, but logs contained only cryptic uninformative Java stacktraces. Something like "Path can't be empty" somewhere inside GCP client library. It was a happy accident to discover the cause outlined in my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently, the spec that Druid UI generates comes in a slightly different JSON format than the one that API consumes. High-level objects in the spec("ioConfig", "dataSchema" and "tuningConfig") should be wrapped in `spec` object, like this:

```
{
    "type": "index_parallel",
    "spec": {
        "dataSchema": {
            "dataSource": "daily_xport_test",
            "granularitySpec": {
                "type": "uniform",
                "segmentGranularity": "MONTH",
                "queryGranularity": "NONE",
                "rollup": false
            },
            "parser": {
                "type": "string",
                "parseSpec": {
                    "format": "json",
                    "timestampSpec": {
                        "column": "dateday",
                        "format": "auto"
                    },
                    "dimensionsSpec": {
                        "dimensions": [{
                                "type": "string",
                                "name": "id",
                                "createBitmapIndex": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "long",
                                "name": "clicks_count_total"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "long",
                                "name": "ctr"
                            },
                            "deleted",
                            "device_type",
                            "target_url"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "ioConfig": {
            "type": "index_parallel",
            "firehose": {
                "type": "static-google-blobstore",
                "blobs": [{
                    "bucket": "data-test",
                    "path": "/sample_data/daily_export_18092019/000000000000.json.gz"
                }],
                "filter": "*.json.gz$"
            },
            "appendToExisting": false
        },
        "tuningConfig": {
            "type": "index_parallel",
            "maxNumSubTasks": 1,
            "maxRowsInMemory": 1000000,
            "pushTimeout": 0,
            "maxRetry": 3,
            "taskStatusCheckPeriodMs": 1000,
            "chatHandlerTimeout": "PT10S",
            "chatHandlerNumRetries": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The UI tries to normalize the spec between a task (batch) and a supervisor (streaming) spec. I have added a Druid issue to address this: https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid/issues/8662